# Prevent Microsoft Office from showing a warning when opening a Project file from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

When I open a `.mpp` file on our SharePoint site, Office displays this warning

[image]

I only see this warning for Project files, I don't see it for Word or Excel files which load into the desktop app.

How do I suppress this warning, so I don't have to accept every time I open an `.mpp` file?

Comment: Try: Run `Internet Options`, Security tab, click Trusted sites, click Sites, enter the SharePoint URL for the project folder (like `https://contoso.sharepoint.com` and if necessary using wildcards), click Add, slide down Security level to Low, then click OK.

Comment: Sigh, group policy prevents me from adding a trusted site. I'll raise a ticket with our Ops team.

Comment: When the bureaucracy finishes its stuff, let me know if it helps and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: @harrymc that did the trick!

Comment: Happy to hear that. I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

- Run *Internet Options > Security tab*
- Click *Trusted sites*
- Click *Sites*
- Enter the SharePoint URL for the project folder
  (such as `https://contoso.sharepoint.com` and if necessary use wildcards)
- Click *Add*
- Slide down the Security level to "Low"
- Click OK.

Comment: And if you're in a corporate environment, you'll need to get the SharePoint site added to the Trusted Sites list rolled out via Group Policy.